# Shut down after YouTube upload is finished

Tags: shutdown, youtube

I upload youtube videos over night using a computer running Ubuntu 11.10 as it really eats my bandwidth. But it's normally done when I'm not around, so it wastes quite a bit of energy leaving it running. Is there any way for me to make it shut down after it's finished?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a browser, you can have a look at uploading [via a script](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/youtube-uploader-nautilus-script-using.html) - you can then create another script which invokes the Youtube Uploader script and then calls the

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

command.

Comment: You should rather run the whole script as root. If you place a sudo command in the script, it will ask you probably for your password after uploading the video.